# Why is my expect().to.have.property() passing even though property is not present?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write tests of my node.js api but encountered a problem when trying to test for a property.
My application is using mongoose. I'm selecting data from mongodb using:

```js
User.findById(req.params.id).select('-refresh_token -password -_id');
```

Response from the query is:

```json
{ 
    login: 'asd', 
    email: 'asd@example.com', 
    role: 'user', 
    __v: 0 
}
```

In my test file I'm using mocha and chai to write integration tests and have a test structured like this:

```js
let response = await UsersController.getUser(req);
console.log(response._id);
expect(response).to.be.a('object');
expect(response).to.have.property('_id');
```

`UsersController.getUser(req)` returns the result of the query so I expect it to not have `_id` property.
When I try to console log it I get `undefined` but my test passes without any problem. When I console log entire response it does not appear to have `_id` property (as expected).

When I test for another property that certainly isn't in my response (e.g. for property `asdasdas`) the test fails.

EDIT

When I add `expect(response).to.not.have.property('_id')` my test fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem seems to be connected with Mongoose's `Document` class. When I change `UsersController.getUser(req)` to `UsersController.getUser(req).toJSON()` everything works as it should and the test fails.

I'm not sure what's the reason for such behavior. It seems like maybe `Document` class instance (my response) somehow has `_id` field but I cannot access it since it was deselected in my query but when I use `toJSON()` on it then I get the object I was looking for and then it does not have `_id` field anymore.